# Boost certain keywords in search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am tryin to boost certain keywords in my mutlimatch query that are more important than other words
data set ['black kurta','blue kurta','green kurta','black pant' ]
eg( search for "black kurta" )
first should be black kurta then 'blue kurta','green kurta' and at last kurta

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Black kurta",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "name^3","meta_title^3","meta_description","short_description","meta_keyword^3","description^1" ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what your index data looks like and/or the index  mappings

Answer (score 0):

Try this, notice the `boost` section.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "black kurta",
                "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "meta_title",
                  "meta_description",
                  "short_description", ...
                ],
                "type": "phrase",
                "boost": 10
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "blue kurta",
                "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "meta_title",
                  "meta_description",
                  "short_description",
                  ...
                ],
                "operator": "and",
                "boost": 4
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "green kurta",
                "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "meta_title",
                  "meta_description",
                  "short_description",
                  ...
                ],
                "operator": "and",
                "boost": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: I do not know all the products in kurta category my aim is to show all kurta with black kurta on top if user searches for black kurta.

currently black kurta is on top with documents having black or kurta so black pants start to show up in the listing